# Using WebSocket without IIS

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, iis, websocket

I was wondering if there's a way to have the WebSocket class do the WebSocket handshake process instead of IIS.

I wrote my own WebSocket TCP server that does exactly that, but I'm not in the mood to write all the opcode/frame checks and decoding when I could be using a class that has been written specifically for that purpose.

Perhaps I could use some hybrid version where I have a separate server that serves the handshake, but then I'm not sure how I can accomplish having two servers listening to the same port. Handshake server + WebSocket server.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any way to utilize the .NET WebSocket class I ended up using a third party library called [SuperWebSocket](http://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/)

It's really easy in use and does everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also XSocket.NET http://xsockets.net/.

I have an implementation of a WebSocket server https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener. It works similarly o a `TcpListener`.