# WebSockets on .Net / c# without IIS (self hosted)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, websocket, windows-services

This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438564/using-websocket-without-iis) but without a conclusion.

I would like to set up a WebSocket server in a self hosted Windows Service where I currently have multiple REST web services running on WCF. My requirements are not that advanced, I just need to consume an incoming stream of data. The problem is that I cannot change the way the data is send, if I could I would just convert it to a streamed HTTP POST, but this is not possible as the protocol is fixed.

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=net-5.0) the WebSocket Class should be available from .NET Framework 4.5 and I am using .NET Framework 4.8 that is also supported but nowhere can I find how to self host it. There are many examples using IIS which I do not use.

So what I want to know is, 1) can the WebSocket class be used to self host a WebSocket Server inside a Windows Service?
If so how is it done? Looking for some example code.

**EDIT**
I think this might be somewhat undocumented but I finally got it to work. The magic seem to be replacing localhost or * with +. The following seem to work hosting the WebSocket while maintaining working WCF web services.

```
WebSocketsServer.Start("http://+:80/Socket/");
```

Some of it was described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-5.0) but I could not make out when to use + or * and what their actual uses are.

> When a port is specified, the host element can be replaced with "*" to
> indicate that the HttpListener accepts requests sent to the port if
> the requested URI does not match any other prefix. For example, to
> receive all requests sent to port 8080 when the requested URI is not
> handled by any HttpListener, the prefix is http://*:8080/. Similarly,
> to specify that the HttpListener accepts all requests sent to a port,
> replace the host element with the "+" character. For example,
> https://+:8080. The "*" and "+" characters can be present in prefixes
> that include paths.

I still do not think this makes sense fully. Anyone have a reference to why this would work?

Comment: If you're not married to the Framework, you could use .NET5 which includes [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel). It being a full-fledged web server makes it more straightforward to do WebSocketing. I think Kestrel can be run on Framework 4.x, though I've never seen it done in the wild.

Comment: You can take a look at this example:[WCF self-hosted WebSocket Service with Javascript client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239953/wcf-self-hosted-websocket-service-with-javascript-client)

Comment: @Jiayao I tried this code before but I could not get it to work. It compiles and runs but there is no documentation or comments on how to get it to work.
I tried running start with "ws://localhost/Socket" and also with "http://localhost/Socket" and it did not work. Tried to make a simple test using curl  but I get the response HTTP/1.1 400 This service does not support WebSocket connections.

Comment: @NPras will eventually upgrade to .NET5 I think but I have around 50 other REST web services and I think it would be a too big update right now

Comment: @Jiayao tried that code again and it worked but there is a major showstopper that it cannot coexist with my REST web services via WCF. If I would switch to port 81 the code seem to work. But I would like to run on standard port 80. Is HttpListener not compatible with WCF ?

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se You can check to see if the server port trusts the application or is not working because port 80 is occupied by the application.

Comment: @www.jensolsson.se  is it possible to post some code , i am doing the same thing but cant find any examples online